# php split a date range into 2 separate ranges

Tags: php, date, split

I would like to know if its possible to split a given date range into 2 separate dates ranges if some certain criteria is met?

I am building a holiday booking system and need to split dates if holiday is booked off over 2 years. Example:

```
start date: 22-12-2013
end date: 04-01-2014
```

With the dates above i would like to split them into 2 lots of date ranges, so i would end up with something like this:

```
start date: 22-12-2013
end date: 31-12-2013
```

and then:

```
start date: 01-01-2014
end date: 04-01-2014
```

Is this possible? If so can someone point me in the right direction in what i need to search for in google?

Comment: So you need to exclude certain dates from given dates range?

Comment: no, basically when a date range hits a certain date (in the above example 31-12-2013) i need that date range to end. and then create a another new date range with the remaining dates. Does that make sense?

Comment: Splitting the date with month  or what ?

Comment: at the end of the year

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a really basic approach, but I think it could be interesting investigating on something like this:

```
$date1 = '22-12-2013';
$date2 = "04-01-2014";

function split_date($d1, $d2)
{
    $start_year = substr($d1, -4);
    $end_year = substr($d2, -4);

    if($end_year > $start_year)
    {
    $d1 .= ' ['.date('d-m-Y',strtotime("last day of December".$start_year)).'] <br />';
    $d2 = '['.date('d-m-Y',strtotime("first day of January".$start_year)).'] ' . $d2;
    }
    return $d1 . $d2;
}

echo split_date($date1, $date2);
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php

Comment: thanks for the answer, when i try this i get the following dates returned:

22-12-2013 [01-01-1970] 
[01-01-1970] 04-01-2014

Comment: Hmm, maybe some problem related to timezone settings. Just for a test  please try adding `date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');` at the beginning.

Comment: is there a way to echo out the new date ranges seperatly with this function?

Comment: Do you mean `return array($d1, $d2)` ?

Answer (score 4):

if you want to split more months you can use this function:

```
function getMonthRanges($start, $end) {
    $timeStart = strtotime($start);
    $timeEnd   = strtotime($end);
    $out       = [];

    $milestones[] = $timeStart;
    $timeEndMonth = strtotime('first day of next month midnight', $timeStart);
    while ($timeEndMonth < $timeEnd) {
        $milestones[] = $timeEndMonth;
        $timeEndMonth = strtotime('+1 month', $timeEndMonth);
    }
    $milestones[] = $timeEnd;

    $count = count($milestones);
    for ($i = 1; $i < $count; $i++) {
        $out[] = [
            'start' => $milestones[$i - 1], // Here you can apply your formatting (like "date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $milestones[$i-1])") if you don't won't want just timestamp
            'end'   => $milestones[$i] - 1
        ];
    }

    return $out;
}
```

Using:

```
$result = getMonthRanges('15-11-2014', '19-11-2014');
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [start] => 1418594400
            [end] => 1420063199
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [start] => 1420063200
            [end] => 1422741599
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [start] => 1422741600
            [end] => 1425160799
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [start] => 1425160800
            [end] => 1426715999
        )

)
```

Human readable result:

```
array_walk_recursive($result, 'applyFormat');

function applyFormat(&$item)
{
    $item = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $item);
}

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [start] => 2014-12-15 00:00:00
            [end] => 2014-12-31 23:59:59
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [start] => 2015-01-01 00:00:00
            [end] => 2015-01-31 23:59:59
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [start] => 2015-02-01 00:00:00
            [end] => 2015-02-28 23:59:59
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [start] => 2015-03-01 00:00:00
            [end] => 2015-03-18 23:59:59
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to ilpaijin, this is what i came up with:

```
$date1 = '22-12-2013';
$date2 = "04-01-2014";

function split_date($d1, $d2)
{
    $start_year = substr($d1, -4);
    $end_year = substr($d2, -4);

    if($end_year > $start_year)
    {
    $d1 .= ' ['.date('d-m-Y',strtotime("31-12-".$start_year)).'] <br />';
    $d2 = '['.date('d-m-Y',strtotime("01-01-".$start_year."+1 years")).'] ' . $d2;
    }
    return $d1 . $d2;
}

echo split_date($date1, $date2);
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of anyone want to split date range for any number of years, following is the implementation.

```
$date1 = '22-12-2013';
$date2 = '04-01-2017';
$dA = array();

function split_date($d1, $d2, &$dA)
{
    $start_year = substr($d1, -4);
    $end_year = substr($d2, -4);

    if($end_year > $start_year)
    {
    $dA[] = $d1;    
        $dA[] = date('d-m-Y',strtotime("31-12-".$start_year));
        if($end_year - $start_year == 1)
        {
            $dA[] = date('d-m-Y',strtotime("01-01-".$start_year."+1 years"));
            $dA[] = $d2;
        }else
        {
            split_date(date('d-m-Y',strtotime("01-01-".$start_year."+1 years")), $d2, $dA);
        }
    }else if($end_year == $start_year)
    {
        $dA[] = $d1;
        $dA[] = $d2;
    }
}

split_date($date1, $date2, $dA);
print_r($dA);


//Answer

Array
(
[0] => 22-12-2013
[1] => 31-12-2013
[2] => 01-01-2014
[3] => 31-12-2014
[4] => 01-01-2015
[5] => 31-12-2015
[6] => 01-01-2016
[7] => 31-12-2016
[8] => 01-01-2017
[9] => 04-01-2017
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Very Simple way. You can split date range Supports for all types of date format.

```
function split_date($start_date,$end_date){

    while($start_date < $end_date){
        $end = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("Last day of December", strtotime($start_date)));
        if($end_date<$end){
            $end = $end_date;
        }
        $dates[] =array('start'=>$start_date,'end'=>$end);

        $start_date =date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($end)));

    }
    return $dates; 
}
$dates = split_date('2011-01-02','2013-01-04');
print_r($dates);
```

**OUPTPUT**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [start] => 2011-01-02   //start date
            [end] => 2011-12-31
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [start] => 2012-01-01
            [end] => 2012-12-31
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [start] => 2013-01-01
            [end] => 2013-01-04  //end date
        )

)
```

Comment: That's almost the best answer, but it fails when the range is just one day between two years. Example: split_date('2021-12-31', '2022-01-01');
In this case, the function return just one array with start and end date 2021-12-31.

Comment: To correct the error you should change the second line to `while($start_date <= $end_date){`